# How to save a file to a model using upload_to for dynamic paths

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-file-upload

I am trying to create a folder for each users to put their project in. So their file will have the path `..\project\id\filename`, `id` is the user `id` and `filename` is the name of the file. Now using the arguments allowed for `upload_to` (`instance` and `filename`) in the `Filefield`, I realize that `instance.id` will be `None` and the path to the file will be `..\project\None\filename` instead of `..\project\id\filename`.

Now reading the [Django documentation upload_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) I saw this:

> In most cases, this object will not have been saved to the database
>   yet, so if it uses the default AutoField, it might not yet have a
>   value for its primary key field.

My interpretation is that creating a new record and `user_directory_path` are not instantiated at the same time, that is, when I call `create` on `Project` model, `instance.id` will be `None`. My question is now, is there a way to get around this? While I see `upload_to` convenient, it is not necessarily convenient for dynamic path such as the one I am doing. I was thinking of creating the record, then adding the file path in an update, but I am in search of a way that can save everything in one step.

```
models.py
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return 'project/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)


class Project(models.Model):

     email = models.ForeignKey(User,
                          to_field="email",
                          max_length=50
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path, validators=[validate_file_type], null=True)
```

This is `views.py` when the form passes validation. Notice `user_directory_path` is called just before the `create`.

```
email = request.user.email
title = request.POST.get('title', '')
file = request.FILES['file']
filename = file.name
instance = Usermie.objects.get(email=request.user.email)

# Save to model
user_directory_path(instance=instance, filename=filename)
Project.objects.create(
    title=title,  file=file,
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If, as you say, the id that you want to use in the file path is the id of the User, not the id of the Project.. then there's no problem because the User already exists when you are saving the Project.  Since `email` is a foreign key to `User`, you would just do:

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return 'project/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.email.id, filename)
```

But I will point out that, in the Django way of doing things, making a field called `email` that is a foreign key to `User` is actually pretty confusing.  The field in the database will be called `email_id`.. and the value of the model field will return an instance of `User`.. not the actual email address,  even though the email address is what's stored in the column.  To get the email address you'd need to do one of:

```
myproject.email.email    
myproject.email_id
```

Neither one is very clear.  So unless you have a really good reason for doing it like that, you should call the field `user` and eliminate the `to_field='email'`.  Allow Django to join the tables via `id`, which is the default behavior.

Then if you need the user email address you can get it any time via

```
 myproject.user.email
```

And the bonus is that if the user changes their email address it will change everywhere, you don't have to rely on cascaded updates to fix all the foreign keys.

Trust me, when using Django you want to do ForeignKey by `id` (the default) unless there's a reason...

Comment: `And the bonus is that if the user changes their email address it will change everywhere, you don't have to rely on cascaded updates to fix all the foreign keys.` very good reason to use `id` in ForeignKey.

Comment: Thanks! This actually gave me a better in sight. I will go back and change my email fields in all other models to the user id. I did not realize the problem of users changing emails until now. Thanks @MHassan. I always knew about this but did not realize I was doing it.

Comment: You're welcome glad I could help.  The other thing I should mention is that once you've created the project you can't allow the user to change because that would change the directory path and the files would no longer be found by django.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution can be saving object without file and then saving file like this

```
email = request.user.email
title = request.POST.get('title', '')
file = request.FILES['file']
filename = file.name
instance = Usermie.objects.get(email=request.user.email)

# Save to model
user_directory_path(instance=instance, filename=filename)
project = Project.objects.create(title=title)
project.file = file
project.save()
```

Comment: This is a nice way of looking at it, but doing like this I will not get the primary key of user, but the primary key of the project model will be used instead.

Comment: In that case, you should write `'project/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.email_id, filename)` as `email` field is foreign key to `User` model.

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying, but because my email field has attribute `to_field="email"` it will return a path `project/user_email/filename`. I might have to switch somethings around for it to work. Thanks!

Comment: if you want to access some other field in User table, you can use double underscore `__` like `project/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.email__id, filename)` or `project/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.email.id, filename)`. Hope this will work.